# Issue on running MVC3 application on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have published the website to sitecloud.cytanium.com (ASP.net MVC3+MYSQL+EntityFramework). Please help me out with this.

The Error I am facing on login is :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +1425695
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString) +27

[ArgumentException: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString) +92
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) +246
```

...........................

Answer (score 0):

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

You should install provider for `MYSQL` on the server. `Connector/Net` or some other.

Same question:

[C# MySQL Connector works in IDE, not after publish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047730/c-sharp-mysql-connector-works-in-ide-not-after-publish)